# mongodb aggregate by month+date and sort it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created this aggregate operation to return a list of list of orders, for each month. That is, something like this:

```
month1: [orders],
month2: [orders],
...
```

However, I wanted it sorted from most recent to least recent month. You can see that my group is the concatenation month+year with a catch. If I simply did month+year, then sorting things would not work:

```
MYYYY
12020
22020
...
92020
102020
```

as you can see, when we reach month 10, the order is broken. The catch was to add `10` to every month, so we end up with

```
MYYYY
112020
122020
...
192020
202020
212020
222020
102021
```

for which ordering works, but then breaks at the next year, 2021.

So how can I order by month+year in a way that I can sort but in a way that I can also display things beautifully in the response? Something easy to parse.

```
        r = await Order.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    launchDate: { "$gte": new Date(req.query.minDate), "$lte": new Date(req.query.maxDate) },
                    withdrawer: { $regex: utils.diacriticSensitiveRegex(req.query.withdrawer), $options: 'i' },
                    deleted: false
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    launchDate: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        $concat: [
                            {
                                $toString: {
                                    $year: "$launchDate"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                $toString: {
                                    $add: [{ $month: "$launchDate" }, 10]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    withdraws: {
                        $push: "$$ROOT"
                    }

                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    _id: -1
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    dateRange: "$_id"
                }
            },
            {
                $skip: skip
            },
            {
                $limit: perPage
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: You put the month first inthe MYYYY format, but it seems you want to have the year as the primary sorting. I would expect you would need a format more in line with YYYYM. Or maybe your format is more for presentation?

Comment: Use two digits for months and put year at the beginning, i.e. use format `%Y-%m`. Another solution is: first use `$sort: {launchDate:1}` by Date value, then do the `$group`. Of course, you must not sort the result again after the `$group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$group`, you can have multiple sub-elements in your `_id`. This can allow you to have year and month as two separate entities, which you can then present any way you please. Your group and sort would the be:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {
                $year: "$launchDate"
            },
            month: {
                $month: "$launchDate"
            }
        },
        withdraws: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }

    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "_id.year": 1,
        "_id.month": 1
    }
},
```

In the example above I have assumed that you want to sort on the year as the primary and month as the secondary both in ascending order, e.g. you'll get jan 2019, feb 2019, ..., jan 2020, feb 2020, mar 2020.

If you would like to to have a formatted version of the year and month, you can of course add it in an `$addFields` or as part of the `$group`. E.g.:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        formatted: {
            $concat:[
                {$toString:"$_id.year"},
                {$cond: {if: {$lt: ["$_id.month", 10]}, then: "0", else: ""}},
                {$toString: "$_id.month"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternative**

Use the `$dateToString` to format your date in your `$group` under `_id` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/). The following should do the trick:

```
{ $dateToString: {
    date: "$launchDate",
    format: ""%Y%m"
} }
```

Comment: I didn't get how $dateToString helps. It looks like it outputs `20201, 20202, 20203,...` am I rigth? How could this be sorted correctly?

Comment: %m gives you 0-padded month, so it will be 202001, 202002, 202003, which would be correspond to sorting first by year, then by month.